# How to set proxy to hardhat?

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

We will verify the contract after deploy, but I cannot access to the api without proxy.
So how to set proxy to hardhat? Set proxy to hardhat.config.js or something else ?

```
const verify = async (contractAddress, args) => {
    console.log("Verifying contract...")
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Always timeout: https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api

```
05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15,7064,500000,30
Verify Raffle contract...
Verifying contract...
Nothing to compile
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: Failed to send contract verification request.
Endpoint URL: https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api
Reason: Connect Timeout Error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { ProxyAgent, setGlobalDispatcher } = require("undici")

const proxyAgent = new ProxyAgent("http://127.0.0.1:1087")
setGlobalDispatcher(proxyAgent)
```

add this segment above in  `hardhat.config.js` file. do not forget change `http://127.0.0.1:1087` to your own proxy url